# Streaming Promises in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async, promises

Imagine a typical HTTP service that does async db queries. If HTTP requests are received more quickly than the db can complete queries (such as because the db disk or network is slow), the Promises will accumulate in the event loop and presumably cause memory pressure, trigger swap-hang etc. I would rather the HTTP service stop generating requests if the server cannot consume them fast enough.

As a possible solution I was thinking an "asyncLimit" property of the db context (or something else) could indicate that IncomingMessage.reader.pause() should be called. The db query would still be submitted anyway of course since you can't just drop it at that point. But after a while, pause()ing streams should throttle requests. After long enough, kernerl buffers will fill up, client buffers will fill up and clients will stop sending data. Then something may or may not call resume() depending on the state of things (DOS?).

So how would you deal with this scenario?

Of course any async calls could build-up in the event loop and cause problems so it would be nice if the solution was generic to the arguably very differnt async / await idiom. If async / await is thought of as like streaming Promises, the flow control of readable.pipe() could be inspiring.

Comment: A promise sitting there in memory is a very tiny piece of memory and does not affect your server in any meaningful way and node.js is particularly good and efficient at having lots of asynchronous operations in flight while most are waiting for something.  If you overwhelm your server with too many simultaneous connections, you may have connection issues with too many open connections waiting for an answer, but that would be more of an OS and OS configuration issue than anything to do with node.js.

Comment: If you completely control the client library that accesses your server, you can implement limits on how many simultaneous connections a given client makes to your server.  Beyond that, all you can do is start immediately failing and disconnecting new incoming connections with some 5xx error code once your server reaches a predetermined limit.

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is just promises so no real difference whether something is using `await p` to await a promise or `p.then()` to await a promise.  Same impact on the server (just a small promise in memory).

Comment: There is other data that is not insignificant. For each promise, there's an HTTP request and response object and everything that goes with that including any data that was decoded from it. There's no point in having that pile up in memory if you can throttle it like pipe() does with data.

Comment: There's no http response and request object until the connection is actually being processed.  If you're overwhelming your server, the  incoming TCP connection is probably setting in an OS queue waiting for your server to give it some attention.  As I said in other comments, the only way to "throttle" here is to immediately drop incoming connections when you're over some limit.  In larger installations, that may be done by additional hardware in front of the server (such as a load balancer or other security hardware).

Comment: You could attempt to do it on your server, but it's less effective there because you're asking an already over-busy server to handle this.

Comment: I don't get the analogy to `.pipe()`.  It doesn't do any connection management.  It just lets the destination tell it when to stop sending it more data.   There is no such analogy for incoming TCP connections.  You don't get to proactively tell all possible clients out there to stop sending you more connections.  You have to deal with an incoming connection that has already arrived when you're too busy.

Comment: Isn't the usual configuration here done at the TCP level where you configure the max number of incoming/pending connections allowed to sit in the queue.  If that number is exceeded, then all new incoming connections are immediately disconnected.  Isn't this usually configured at the OS level, not at the node.js http server level?  So, if your server gets overly busy and isn't attending to incoming connections, the OS stops sending you more of what you already have too much of.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you don't know what I'm talking about. I'm not talking about manipulating incoming tcp connections. I'm talking about stopping the http module from reading. Also, I'm not talking about the server being "busy". I'm talking about async calls stalling b/c of downstream problems, slowness, failures.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I thought you meant.  What good does it do you to stop the http module from reading?  You'd just be letting your CPU sit idle when it could have otherwise been working on a new connection, the TCP socket is already open so that server resource is already consumed.  If you want to protect your DB from too many requests, you can do that at the DB interface pretty easily.  I don't get what problem blocking http reading from the socket solves.  You'll also be looking at client-side http timeouts and more and more users hitting the stop button or refresh with impatience.

Comment: OK, now I do see the analogy to `.pipe()`, I just don't think it serves a useful purpose for this problem.

Comment: @squarewav Are you looking for streams like "backpressure" and "high watermark"  in HTTP processing, instead of traditional rate-limiter?

Comment: What I'm asking is clearly a little too abstract to get good answers. I'm trying to understand the concept of backpressure but applied to promises in the event queue instead of streams. Backpressure in streams only works when Readable writes to Writable and write() returns false to trigger pause. But the same concept occurs when calling async functions. If the async functions are not resolved as quickly as they're called, they accumulate in the event loop along with anything attached to them like HTTP requests, DB query result sets, data, etc.